# How to create mongodb collection in spring boot without using pojo class?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, pojo

I have a spring boot app with a MongoDB connection. On using the POJO/Model class with @Document(Collection = "CompanyDetails"), it successfully creates the collection in MongoDB after "POSTMAPPING" and the result goes inside the CompanyDetails collection as expected.

I have used controller, service, repository, and used the Map<String, Object> in parenthesis of the repository rather than using POJO class.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/addRecords")
public Map<String, Object> addCompanyDetails(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> companyDetails) {
    return companyDetailsService.addCompanyDetails(companyDetails);
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class CompanyDetailsService {

@Autowired
CompanyDetailsRepository companyDetailsRepository;

public Map<String, Object> addCompanyDetails(Map<String, Object> companyDetails) {
        return companyDetailsRepository.insert(companyDetails);
        
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyDetailsRepository extends MongoRepository<Map<String, Object>, String> {}
```

My requirement is to create a collection without a POJO class. Because, the fields are not fixed(while inserting records). So, I can't declare fields in the POJO class & generate a getter setter.

As I'm not using the POJO class, when I POST record, it creates a collection with the name "map" & insert records inside that.
But, expected was to create "CompanyDetails" collection & store data inside that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, people using MongoDB faced this issue as MongoDB is a schemaless database and creating POJO will be difficult. So, here is the solution for such use-cases.

Firstly, you can use the `MongoClient` to connect with your database. Check out this document for your reference: [Connect to MongoDB](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.3/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/)

Secondly, you can create databases and collections using that `mongoClient object. Check out this document for your reference [Create database and collection](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.3/driver/tutorials/databases-collections/)

Finally, you can use some generic objects like `HashMap` or `BasicDBObject` to perform your CRUD operation